# InvalidKeyException when attempting to encrypt password for Instagram login

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, rsa, instagram

I am building and Instagram bot which needs to login to Instagram. Now I know that Instagram uses an encryption system for its password, and I am trying to follow it but keep running into the

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: null

Basically Instagram needs a cipher text that follow the structure detailed in this [github repo](https://github.com/Datalux/instagram-weak-encryption#encryption-phases). My code is as follows to replicate it.

```
 // Generate a random IV
 byte[] iv = new byte[12];
 new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);

 // Get the system current time in milliseconds
 long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

 // Converting public key to byte array from hex string
 byte[] publicKeyBytes = hexStringToByteArray(publicKey);

 // Create a random key
 byte[] randomKey = new byte[32];
 new SecureRandom().nextBytes(randomKey);

 // rebuild key using SecretKeySpec
 SecretKey publicKeyClass = new SecretKeySpec(randomKey,0, randomKey.length, "AES");

 //generate the cipher text
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKeyClass, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));

 // Add the current time in milliseconds as additional authenticated data
 cipher.updateAAD(Long.toString(timestamp).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
 byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(pwd.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

 // Get the tag from the end of the cipher text
 byte[] tag = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherText, cipherText.length - 16, cipherText.length);

 // Now we encrypt a random key using the same public key
 // use RSA encryption to encrypt the random key
 X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes, "RSA");
 KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
 PublicKey encryptedKeyClass = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
 Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
 cipher2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encryptedKeyClass);
 byte[] encryptedRandomKey = cipher2.doFinal(randomKey);

 // Generate the final encrypted text
 String encryptedText = publicKeyId+encryptedRandomKey.toString()+tag.toString()+cipherText.toString();

 //Base64 encode the encrypted text
 String encryptedTextBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

and the function hexStringtoByteArray

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] =(byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

I realize that it is a lot of code so here is a basic gist of what is going on

1. I pass a password and publickey(string) to the function.
2. We generate a random IV and a new random key.
3. I then use this random key to encrypt the password using AES_GCM_256 bit encryption.
4. Then the publickey(which was given by instagram) is 64 bytes long and appears to be hex encoded. So I decode it and use it as a key to encrypt the randomly generated key that I have created.
5. Finally I combine all of this in the format that insta wants and return the final cipher text.

Now my problem lies in the 4th step.I keep getting the error that the key is of invalid spec. The line that throws the error is

```
PublicKey encryptedKeyClass = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

Example Public Key that Instagram returns

```
c81814218a8fe89a6a5794ff5f2a192bf5ab9d3f7115bc8fbceb7b701079777c
```

I checked multiple online sources and they all seem to follow the same method I am doing. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks !

Comment: Yea sure, just edited the question. @AlexR

Comment: 32 bytes for an RSA key is unrealistic (possibly an EC key). Post a link describing the asymmetric encryption. For later: The chaset decoding with `toString()` of encrypted key, tag and ciphertext corrupts the data.

Comment: @Topaco Here are some links of other people's implementation that all use RSA encryption. Couldn't find a recent one for Java. And thanks for the heads up on the toString().
[python example](https://github.com/adw0rd/instagrapi/blob/3171ec34d62edef8bfef443faa26d26ae5f15b28/instagrapi/mixins/password.py)
[C# implementation](https://gist.github.com/huoshan12345/44b1b4927b21d4ec21d1cbd61ea659da)

Comment: This example does not show a key for length comparison. Secure RSA keys have a length of 2048 bits and X.509 encoded even more. Maybe a different algorithm is used or your public key is wrong.

Comment: @Topaco I added an example key. The original key (the one that is scraped directly of instagram) is 64 bytes and follows the above style. If this is not an RSA key what kind of other encryption could it be?

Comment: Possibly different versions and therefore different algorithms, s. [here](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api/issues/1010). An RSA key looks like [here](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api/issues/1010#issuecomment-564019541), which is an X.509-PEM key (after Base64 decoding). [Here](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api/issues/1010#issuecomment-749533937) different versions are mentioned. [Here](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api/issues/1010) is a Libsodium-based approach (which uses a 32 bytes key).